# Schematron for checking for testing a node if the content of another node matches a value

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0, schematron

I have a set of records that I need to check to make sure a node exists, but only if the record is not of a particular type. For example:

```
<record>
  <type>Audio</type>
</record>
<record>
  <type>Video</type>
</record>
<record>
  <type>Text</type>
  <preview>https://website.com/preview.jpg</preview>
</record>
```

I want to say a record is invalid if it does not have a `<preview>` field, unless it is an audio or video file, in which case not having a `<preview>` field is fine.

But something like this does not work:

```
<pattern>
    <rule context="record/type !='Audio' and record/type !='Video'">
        <assert test="record/preview">Needs preview image</assert>
    </rule>
</pattern>
```

Is there any way to make the test of one node conditional on the value of a different node?

Comment: Doesn't it suffice to use `<rule context="record[not(type = ('Audio', 'Video'))]"><assert test="preview">...</assert></rule>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a rule

```
<rule context="record[not(type = ('Audio', 'Video'))]">
  <assert test="preview">Needs preview image</assert>
</rule>
```

Comment: Excellent--thanks! As written above I get an "invalid expression" error, but something like this works: `'<rule context="record[not(type = 'Audio') and not(type = 'Video')]">`

Comment: @BHammond, the expression I gave should work with Schematron based on XSLT/XPath 2 and later, as you tagged your question as [tag:xslt-2.0] I assumed that version. But you have found an XSLT/XPath 1 alternative that does the job as well.